# VBscript - open particular version of office when two versions are installed

Tags: vbscript, ms-office

I have a problem - I have two versions of MS Office installed - 2007 and 2010. I have a script that needs to open word and excel files in 2007 version.

I have created a procedure that should try to open the 2007 version of office, and in case it fails (for example for a user which doesn't have 2007 version) it opens the default version.

The problem here is that regardless of the existance of 2007, version 2010 is being open. 
If I remove "on error resume" option and change Word.Application.12 to e.g. Word.Application.13 we get an error that no such application can be opened, which is correct - it means that the system does recognize .12 as "something meaningful" - however it doesn't start it.

```
Sub StartWord
On error resume next
        Set appWord = CreateObject("Word.Application.12")
            appWord.visible = false
            appWord.DisplayAlerts = false
        If err.number <> 0 Then
            Set appWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
                appWord.visible = false
                appWord.DisplayAlerts = false
        End if
On error goto 0
End Sub
```

Any clues here?

Comment: you can launch a `WinWord.exe` from a shell with full path name, then `CreateObject()` will be using that version. there is no other way to launch a specific version from VBS as it's assumed to only have 1 version of office suite on a computer.

Comment: Well, unfortunately, opening word from shell doesn't change much. I tried `objShell.Run ("""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\WINWORD.EXE""/regserver"), 0` followed by `Set appWord = CreateObject("Word.Application.12")` but still, script opens office 2010 in spite of having version 2007 running in the background. It's crazy, because if I click the file icon, 2007 is opened by default...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it appears I am going to answer my own question.

In case of Word, I have tested the following behaviour and code:

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run ("""C:\Program Files (x86)\MicrosoftOffice\Office12\WINWORD.EXE""/regserver"), 0
Set objShell = Nothing
wscript.sleep 1000
StartWord

Sub StartWord
Set appWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
appWord.visible = FALSE
appWord.DisplayAlerts = false
End Sub
```

The result here is that correct version of Word is used. However, the same code DOESN'T work for EXCEL.

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run ("""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\EXCEL.EXE""/regserver"), 0
Set objShell = Nothing
wscript.sleep 1000
StartExcel

Sub StartExcel
    Set appExcel = GetObject("", "Excel.Application")
            appExcel.visible = true
            appExcel.DisplayAlerts = false      
End Sub
```

Any idea why are these two pieces of ...Microsoft working differently?